# how to use multiple join sql query in java spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

i want to use multiple join query in java spring boot i can't found answer
so if you know the solution plz comment it

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4 FROM category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id WHERE t1.name = :'ROOT'",nativeQuery = true)
List<Category> findByCategory(String query);
}
```

this is my CategoryRepository Code

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="category_id", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
private int Category_id;
private String name;
private int parent;

}
```

this is my Category code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/category")
@Slf4j
public class CategoryController {
@Autowired CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getDomainList(String query) {
    List<Category> all= this.categoryRepository.findByCategory(query);
    return all.toString();
    //log.info(query);
    //return "Test";
}
}
```

this is my CategoryController Code

so when i run the Code

```
2019-10-31 11:10:30.124  WARN 2356 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2019-10-31 11:10:30.124 ERROR 2356 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : 
Column 'category_id' not found
```

i got the this error message
i really crave to run it.. thanks

Comment: please verify your question again. I think you miss some code.

Comment: thank you for applying  you mean that i missed the all error code log? or which one it? if you tell that i will fix code that which you want it

Comment: What about `Dataset_info` class?

Comment: @hognkun I mean you have problem with CategoryRepository but you submitted  DatasetRepository instead. So how can we help you lol ;)

Comment: i fixed it thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method**

```
String query= "SELECT firewall_items.src, firewalls.info 
FROM firewall_items 
JOIN firewalls 
ON firewall_items.firewalls_id = firewalls.id"
List<Item> items = jdbcTemplate.query(
      query, 
      new MapSqlParameterSource(), 
      new FirewallInfoRowMapper()
      );
```

Comment: thank you for applying 
i changed code  like 
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
    String query= "SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4 FROM category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id WHERE t1.name = 'ROOT'";
    List<Category> items = jdbcTemplate.query(
            query,
            new MapSqlParameterSource()
    );
}

Comment: but i got the 
Error:(14, 28) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable jdbcTemplate
  location: interface kr.co.ds.datastation.dsapi.repository.CategoryRepository

Comment: could you tell me what's the problem

Comment: you need to learn about block scope in Java, for example a variable ans declared in the block of a while loop can't be used outside of that block,
you try to use variable names that haven't been declared

Comment: thank you for applying actually i understand your advice.. so could you give me a way to fix it my code? i am really desperate..

Comment: For this, I have to read the entire code, then I will fix the bug. But i haven't  time @hognkun, Please don't desperate , Have a little refresh then try after

Comment: i appreciate that plz if you fix it adding comment !