# How to create a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am learning JPA so I want to use mysql query like this

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4 
FROM category AS t1 LEFT 
JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id 
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id 
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ROOT'
```

so how to change this to jpql query code?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a JPA query with LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202456/how-to-create-a-jpa-query-with-left-outer-join)?

Comment: I have updated the  answer , could you please looking to that

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring data jpa , you could provide it in the repository layer like :

```
@Repository
    public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {
        @Query( value = 
        "SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4 
        FROM category AS t1
        LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
        LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id 
        LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
        WHERE t1.name = 'ROOT'",
         nativeQuery = true)
        List<Category> fetchCategoryDataLeftJoin();

    }
```

Comment: i try it but.. i got the debug...antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: t1

Comment: @hognkun At first you should create `Category` entity and `DeptEmpDto` with constructor like this  `DeptEmpDto(String lev1, String lev2, String lev3, String lev4)`. Then add this code to your question

Comment: @hognkun Could you please share the code that you have tried out , as well as the stacktrace.

Comment: you should remove the alias from query

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using EntityManager you can follow this way**

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("SELECT t1.name , t2.name , t3.name , t4.name  
FROM category  t1 LEFT 
JOIN category  t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id 
LEFT JOIN category  t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id 
LEFT JOIN category  t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = :name"); // :name - you can pass parameter here 

Query q = entityManager.createQuery(sb.toString());


 q.setParameter("name", "ROOT");//Root is the value and name is the parameter
```

**Remove the alias from query and run it**

```
select t1.name , t2.name , t3.name , t4.name  
from  category  t1 left 
join category  t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id 
left join category  t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id 
left join category  t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ROOT'
```

Comment: thanks but i cant use entityManager.. i don't know why.. so your answer is not for me..

Comment: I have updated the answer please looking to and  make sure to remove alias from query

Comment: i changed code after that i got the this debug message..
2019-10-31 16:45:59.279  WARN 4740 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2019-10-31 16:45:59.279 ERROR 4740 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'category_id' not found.

Comment: How you changed did you remove alias

Comment: Could you please with check with your entity , if it is existing or not

Comment: can i comment some link which my source code  register in stack overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636081/how-to-use-multiple-join-sql-query-in-java-spring-boot